# How to write a where.not query with multiple conditions in rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

What I want to express is this:

```
Model.where("a IS NOT NULL `**`OR`**` b IS NOT NULL")
```

In Rails 4, `where.not` clause is enabled:

```
Model.where.not(a: nil, b: nil)
```

However, This expression equals

```
Model.where("a IS NOT NULL `**`AND`**` b IS NOT NULL")
```

How can I express

```
"a IS NOT NULL `**`OR`**` b IS NOT NULL"
```

with `where.not` clause?

Answer (score 14):

### Important: Rails 6.1 changes the behavior of `where.not` with multiple attributes!

---

#### Up to Rails 5.2 - NOR ( NOT(A) AND NOT(B) ).

Up to Rails 5.2, if we use `where.not` with multiple attributes, it applies logical `NOR (NOT(A) AND NOT(B))` in `WHERE` clause of the query.

```rb
Post.where.not(source_type: "Feed", source_id: 100).to_sql

# => SELECT "posts".* FROM "posts" WHERE "posts"."source_type" != 'Feed' AND "posts"."source_id" != 100
```

#### Rails 6 - NOR ( NOT(A) AND NOT(B) ) with deprecation.

Rails 6 adds a deprecation warning.

```rb
Post.where.not(source_type: "Feed", source_id: 100)

DEPRECATION WARNING: NOT conditions will no longer behave as NOR in Rails 6.1.
To continue using NOR conditions, NOT each conditions manually 
(`.where.not(:source_type => ...).where.not(:source_id => ...)`).
```

#### Rails 6.1+ - NAND ( NOT(A) OR NOT(B) ).

Rails 6.1+ will change `where.not` working to `NAND (NOT(A) OR NOT(B))`.

```rb
Post.where.not(source_type: "Feed", source_id: 100).to_sql

# => SELECT "posts".* FROM "posts" WHERE ("posts"."source_type" != 'Feed' OR "posts"."source_id" != 100)
```

---

Sources:

- [Rails 6 deprecates where.not as NOR & Rails 6.1 as NAND](https://web.archive.org/web/20201107233046/https://blog.bigbinary.com/2019/07/31/rails-6-deprecates-where-not-working-as-nor-and-will-change-to-nand-in-rails-6-1.html).
- [Link to the corresponding PR](https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/36029).
- [Link to the relevant discussion](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/31209).

Comment: This doesn't answer the question

Comment: I'm not seeing an `OR` on Rails 6.1:


`> User.where.not(email: "test@test.com", name: "test name").to_sql`

`=> "SELECT \"users\".* FROM \"users\" WHERE NOT (\"users\".\"email\" = 'test@test.com' AND \"users\".\"name\" = 'test name')"`

Comment: It's shocking to me that a) this helpful stackoverflow user deems this important enough to write **Important !** in this answer and b) This fundamental breaking change is not mentioned anywhere in the official Rails upgrade 
page https://guides.rubyonrails.org/upgrading_ruby_on_rails.html Thanks for the clear answer Marian13

Answer (score 11):

You could create your query as you've tried with `where.not` for the `a` and `b` attribute:

```
query = Model.where.not(a: nil, b: nil)
```

And then use `inject` in the `where` values for the query created before by passing the `or` operator:

```
Model.where(query.where_values.inject(:or))
```

This will give you a query like:

```
SELECT "model".*
FROM "model"
WHERE (
  "model"."a" IS NOT NULL OR
  "model"."b" IS NOT NULL
)
```

Despite of the first one which gives you something using the `AND` operator, like:

```
SELECT "model".*
FROM "model"
WHERE ("model"."a" IS NOT NULL) AND
      ("model"."b" IS NOT NULL)
```

Answer (score 9):

There is no rails-way to do this in rails 4.

You could try [rails_or](https://github.com/khiav223577/rails_or) which give you `or` and `or_not` method:

```
Model.where.not(a: nil).or_not(b: nil)
```

Or upgrade to rails 5 and write the query as:

```
Model.where.not(a: nil).or(Model.where.not(b: nil))
```

Comment: Getting undefined method or_not

Comment: Sadly, [or_not](https://github.com/khiav223577/rails_or#or_not) is only supported in rails 4.0.2+ since [where.not](https://apidock.com/rails/v4.0.2/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods/WhereChain/not) was not defined until then.